# Updating an array during a timer in useEffect react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout, use-effect

I'm having trouble getting my head round updating an array during a timer in the useEffect hook:

```
    const [data, setData] = useState(0)
    const [priceList, setPriceList] = useState([])
    const [profit, setProfit] = useState(0)


    useEffect(() => {
        let value = 1000

        const update_value = () => {
            if (Math.random() >= 0.5 || value - Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 100 < 0) {
                return value += Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 100
            }
            return value -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 100
        }

        const price_fluctuation = (d) => {
            if (priceList.length < 2) {
                setPriceList([d, ...priceList])
                return d
            } else {
                let oldList = [...priceList]
                oldList.pop()
                setPriceList([d, ...oldList])
                return d - priceList[1]
            }
        }

        const timer = () => {
            let totalTimer = (5 * 60 + 1) * 1000
            let timerId = setInterval(
                () => {
                    const current_price = update_value()
                    setData(current_price)
                    setProfit(price_fluctuation(current_price))

                }, 5000);

            setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(timerId); }, totalTimer);
        }
        timer()

    }, [])
```

The function price_fluctuation takes the current price and adds it to an array which is then set to priceList. The function is meant to at most holds two prices the current price and previous price. However the priceList never gets set during the timer I believe this is because priceList is always initialised to an empty array.

What can I do to have my function work as intended during the timer. I believe I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: setState is async function. You have to use callbacks.

Comment: I tried setPriceList(()=>[d, ...oldList])

Comment: I would seriously recommend declaring the fn outside of useEffect. Moreover, your priceList state is not inside the dependency array of useEffect, meaning it does not get the updated values. If you don't need it in your dependency array, then you can try working with refs, but it's a bit of overkill.